# Superclass constraints vs. instance declarations in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

It kind of seems like in Haskell one can use instance declarations similarly to superclass constraints. I'll give an example using `Semigroup` and `Monoid` from Prelude. Here's a simplified definition of `Semigroup`:

```
class Semigroup a where
        (<>) :: a -> a -> a
```

Here's a simplified version of Prelude's definition of `Monoid` which uses a superclass constraint:

```
class Semigroup a => Monoid a where
        mempty  :: a
        mappend :: a -> a -> a
        mappend = (<>)
```

If I'm not mistaken it seems the superclass constraint could be replaced by an instance declaration as follows:

```
class Monoid a where
        mempty  :: a
        mappend :: a -> a -> a

instance Monoid a => Semigroup a where
        (<>) = mappend
```

Is there a reason for Haskell to have superclass constraints when it seems one can do the same with instance declarations (with constraints)? Which one should be preferred? Is it superclass constraints whenever possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a fundamental error in how you're reading the instance constraint. It is important (and not obvious at first) to remember that constraints on instances are checked ***after*** committing to the instance.

To see whether an instance matches a given type you **only** look at the stuff to the right of the `=>` (the **instance head**). If it matches then the compiler commits to the instance and the constraints on the instance become additional requirements for the typechecker to consider. If those fail you will have a type error; it's too late to consider another instance<sup>1</sup>. The compiler will only consider other instances if the instance head does not match at all.

This means that `instance Monoid a => Semigroup a` does *not* mean "any type that is a `Monoid` is a `Semigroup`". Rather it means "*every* type `a` is a `Semigroup`, but to use any `Semigroup` methods with `a` requires you to prove `Monoid a` first".

As a consequence of these rules, there can be no other `Semigroup` instances (because `instance ... => Semigroup a` matches every type). Which means the implication of the instance you wrote is actually backwards from the original class constraint: `class Semigroup a => Monoid a` means "if a type is a `Monoid` then it is also a `Semigroup`", whereas `instance Monoid a => Semigroup a` effectively means "if a type is a `Semigroup` then it is also a `Monoid`".

That's all you really need to know. The answer to your question about why both features exist is trivially "they're not the same", and the answer to which should be preferred is pretty clear once you know what they both mean; since they mean different things you have to consider what you want to say and use the most appropriate feature on a case by case basis. The rest of this answer is trying to explain why the compiler works this way; I find it's more intuitive when you understand the problems the rules are trying to avoid.

---

The reason for these rules is basically to support separate compilation of modules while trying to retain coherence of the type class system (meaning that any time we resolve an instance for a given type we want to be able to assume it will be the exact same instance definition, consistently across an entire multi-package program, no matter how we found it; APIs like `Data.Map` fundamentally rely on this property). The compiler only processes one module at a time (and its imports, to a lesser degree), so it doesn't want to assume that it can see every single instance declaration that will be used in the final complete program. That means the compiler never wants to do anything that would only be correct if an instance does *not* exist just because it hasn't seen such an instance.

This is the guiding principle that explains everything: the compiler can only ever use *positive* information about instances (that a type *does* have an instance) to compile your program. It will only ever use negative information (that an instance appears to be missing) to reject your program, never to accept it.

So more concretely, if we have:

```
module Monoid where

class Monoid a where
  mappend :: a -> a -> a
  mempty :: a

class Semigroup a where
  (<>) :: a -> a -> a

instance Monoid a => Semigroup a where
  (<>) = mappend
```

and also

```
module DataDefinition where

data Example = Constructor
```

and finally

```
module DataUsage where

import DataDefinition
import Monoid

foo :: Example -> Example -> Example
foo x y = x <> y
```

The compiler will reject `foo` because of a missing `Monoid` instance for `Example`, not a missing `Semigroup` instance. It has to resolve the `Semigroup Example` constraint using the `Monoid a => Semigroup a` instance; because another module in the final program (importing both `Monoid` and `DataDefinition`, but not importing or imported by `DataUsage`) might theoretically have a `Monoid Example` instance and also use the `Module a => Semigroup a` instance for `Example`. If that happened then the only way to maintain the property that the entire program always uses the same `Semigroup` instance for `T` is that inside `DataUsage` we have to use the `Monoid a => Semigroup a` one  as well. And since we can't rule out whether that happens in another module, we have to do that **regardless** of whether it actually does happen! But that then requires we have to look for a `Monoid T` instance, which we don't find, and we're allowed to use the non-existence of the `Monoid` instance to report an error.

If we wanted `T` to be a `Semigroup` only and add:

```
instance Semigroup T where
  C <> C = C
```

then we get an error about overlapping instances because `instance Semigroup T` and `instance Monoid a => Semigroup a` **both** match the usage in `bar`. The logic that we can't allow this is a bit more subtle, but it comes down to the same thing. Another module could conceivably be working with `T` without actually knowing it, via instantiation of a polymorphic type. That module wouldn't use the specific `Semigroup T` instance (because it's working with a polymorphic type, not `T` specifically). But it might use the `Monoid a => Semigroup a` instance, and if it was ever called on `T` (which would require there to be a `Monoid T` instance out there somewhere that isn't imported into the `DataUsage` module we're compiling right now) then it would use the general `Semigroup` instance with `T`, instead of using the `T`-specific one. So since we can't rule that out *we* can't use the specific one either! Since that reasoning would always apply when you have both a specific and a general instance that can match the same type, overlapping instances are simply reported as an error in themselves (although I believe only when trying to solve a related constraint; you might technically be able to include overlapping instances if you never attempt to use them with any types they both match).

---

There are compiler extensions in GHC that allow you to relax these rules, permitting multiple overlapping instances to be used by choosing the "best match" at each use site rather than requiring that there only ever be a single possible match. I'll leave it to the [appropriate section in the GHC users guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/instances.html?highlight=overlapping#instance-overlap) to explain all the gory details.

This can be a powerful feature, but it can also be a bit fragile; if GHC picks a different instance from the available ones that match than you thought it would that can often cause subtle bugs that are difficult to diagnose. In my experience overlapping is more often used for special-purpose classes where a single library provides all of the instances that are expected to exist, rather than with general-purpose things like `Semigroup` that are expected to be widely instantiated across many packages.

I don't recommend you try using overlapping instances until you're really very familiar and comfortable with the normal instance resolution rules, and know that you're trying to do something that cannot be modelled well without overlapping instances. Especially I don't recommend seeing overlapping instances as a way to write "universal" instances like `instance Monoid a => Semigroup a`, *just* to avoid writing easy instances for each type. It looks tempting, but I don't think it's worth it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually if there are other instances whose heads matched that in itself would be detected as an error!

Comment: The third paragraph is excellent. Petition to add it as a quote to every typeclass introduction from now on.

Comment: A thorough explanation, thanks. I guess this explains why superclass constraints are necessary.

Answer (score 6):

This instance has a main downside:

```
instance Monoid a => Semigroup a where
        (<>) = mappend
```

First, the positive side: the instance does cause each monoid type to become a semigroup, as wanted.

However, it is not accepted unless we enable `UndecidableInstances`. It is not a huge downside, since this is a mostly benign extension, but it is something that has to be kept in mind.

The main issue, though, is that the instance prevents any other type from being a semigroup. More precisely, it prevents us to define any semigroup that is not a monoid.

This is because once we have an instance of the form

```
instance ... => Semigroup a where
   ...
```

then this will *overlap* with any other instance for `Semigroup`, triggering errors.

```
data T = T
instance Semigroup T where
   ...

Overlapping instances for Semigroup T
     Matching instances:
       instance Monoid a => Semigroup a
       instance Semigroup T
```

Effectively, this limits semigroups to being those type that are also monoids.

In theory, one might lift this restriction enabling the overlapping instances extension, but that is generally regarded as a bad idea. Once we do so, the instance selection rules become more complex and fragile. Now, if one is careful about which instances are in scope, e.g. avoiding orphan instances, one can live with overlapping instances. Still, they are best to be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 6):

If you write `instance Monoid a => Semigroup a` you're essentially declaring `Semigroup` to be a **synonym** of `Monoid`. With that instance in place, all `Monoid` instances will be `Semigroup` instances – so far it's like the real superclass relation. But vice versa any constraint `Semigroup a` appearing anywhere in your code will immediately match the instance head, i.e. effectively you also have the relationship the other way around: the only way for a type to be an instance of `Semigroup` happens to be by first being an instance of `Monoid`, which is of course not what you wanted.

There's a way to circumvent this: you *could* still have overlapping instances that instantiate `Semigroup` without `Monoid`. Or rather, you could make it

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Monoid a => Semigroup a
```

But **I would advise against this**: overlapping instance are IMO fundamentally violating the principle of how typeclasses work in Haskell, they regularly lead to weird surprises, and it's unnecessary because Haskell already has a good way of declaring this relationship: by making `Semigroup` a superclass of `Monoid`!

There is one caveat to this, and it admittedly a situation that turns up quite a lot: if you can't control `class B`, and you write your own `class A`, and it *should* be a superclass of `B` but you can't change `B`. In fact, exactly that **has** happened historically: before GHC-8, [the `Monoid` class had no superclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html), and `Semigroup` was [defined in a separate package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.12.1/docs/Data-Semigroup.html).

I don't really know a good solution for that situation. Best is if you can convince the maintainer of `B` to pull your `A` superclass into the package to have the proper `A => B` superclass relationship. Short of that, it can sometimes help to write a new class

```
class (A x, B x) => B' x
instance (A x, B x) => B' x
```

Comment: You said: "the only way for a type to be an instance of `Semigroup` happens to be by first being an instance of `Monoid`". I don't understand why that would be the case. This one instance declaration shouldn't prevent declaring other types that are not instances of `Monoid` as instances of `Semigroup`.

Comment: @QuantumWiz but it _does_ prevent such instances. (Or rather, as I mentioned, these would need to overlapping instances, and you don't want overlapping instances – unless you have an extremely good reason.)

Comment: OK, I read the GHC User's Guide on instance resolution and I think I now somewhat understand what you were saying. I have to say this was a bit surprising to me. I guess it explains why superclass constraints are definitely needed in Haskell.

Comment: Now I'm struggling to decide whether to accept your answer or the one by chi.

Comment: @QuantumWiz I think this answer describes the issue better than mine. Yes, instance resolution is a bit surprising at first, but it follows a simple principle: no backtracking. Haskell never tries an instance, then observes that it leads to failure, and then tries another one. If that happened, resolution could be exp-time. To avoid that, the simplest option is to disallow overlaps, and use a greedy instance search: as soon an an instance matches, we commit to it. Another option is to allow overlaps and use "priority" to drive the search, but that can be fragile in practice.

Comment: @chi Now there's a new answer by Ben which is even more explicit about the instance resolution logic so I think I'll accept that.

Answer (score 2):

In your example both definitions are equivalent since one can derive the `<>` implementation using `mappend`. There is a slight difference that may not be immediately apparent:

```
class Semigroup a => Monoid a where ...
```

Means that for `a` to be a `Monoid` it must first be a `Semigroup`

```
class Monoid a where ...
instance Monoid a => Semigroup a where ...
```

Means that if `a` is a `Monoid` then it's also a `Semigroup` and you state that by providing the instance implementation.
In the first case one who wants to implement an instance of `Monoid` for his own data type will have to also implement a `Semigroup` instance:

```
newtype PlusInt = I Int 

class Semigroup a => Monoid a where ...

instance Monoid PlusInt where 
    mempty = I 0 
    mappend (I n) (I m) = I $ n + m
-- ^ Error: No instance for (Semigroup PlusInt)
```

So which one to use really depends on the case:

- by definition a `Monoid` must be a `Semigroup` so the definition is `class Semigroup a => Monoid a where ...`
- by definition an `Applicative` must be a `Functor` so the type class is `class Functor f => Applicative f where ...`
- If `a` is a `Semigroup` then `Maybe a` is a `Semigroup` so you have an instance declaration like `instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Maybe a) where ...`
- ...